# In JavaFX, Is there a best practice or framework for creating program help files?

Tags: javafx

I've been experimenting with using HTML as a structure for generating a help information area for a desktop program that I've finished writing and that seems to work ok, though I don't really like the way it is turning out and I began to wonder if perhaps there might be a better way to go about it. Perhaps a library that makes generating and linking content within Java a little easier in that context or some other means that I'm not aware of.

I did some Googling on the topic but found nothing specifically in reference to help menu / content creation.

Does anyone know of any libraries out there that would make it easier to create help info for end users?

Or, is there a "best practice" for doing this or any other method to that end?

Thank you,

Mike

Comment: Library recommendations are out of scope for StackOverflow, but, that aside, I don't understand exactly what you really want to do.   Nevertheless, I'll make a guess is that you just want a decent doc editing platform and some way to tie it into your app, so I'll try to provide general info on that with a focus on what Idea appears to do.

Comment: This question seems off-topic. I have a very small app [here](https://github.com/james-d/ZoomingMandelbrot) which has a simple help browser. Not sure how well that would scale.

Comment: Perhaps a better scope match for this question would have been [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), though, if you did ask there, I would never have seen or attempted to answer it.  I do think that the question could have benefited from clearly addressing the asking suggestions for recommendations: "1. A purpose — a task to accomplish, a user story 2. Some objective requirements — a minimum set of features".

Comment: @James_D I started building the help content with HTML, but as I said I wasn't happy with the way it was turning out, so I just wondered if there was "something" else out there that I'm not aware of for building help content, but it seems that HTML is the preferred way to do it ... which is a perfectly acceptable answer. I'm not sure how this is off-topic exactly, could you explain that to me, please?

Comment: This seems inherently opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

**What does Idea do?**

Intellij is large java app that has [decent help documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started.html). You could look and see how they did that, if that is something you wish to emulate. I think it is mostly good quality writing and organization rather than tool support, though I guess they use decent tooling too.

I did a quick check to see how idea create their doc. They write in markdown format. Here is the markdown style guide they use for creating the document, in [generated html form](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/sdk-style.html) and in [markdown authoring form](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs/main/topics/intro/sdk_style.md). A repository of docs used for one of their products is their open source [sdk docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs). The SDK docs project is an Idea project, so I guess they just use Idea for authoring.  If it seems to be something that would help you, you could try cloning the project and generating documentation from it or contacting the project contributors for more info.

As far as tying the help content into your app, either you can display it in situ using a WebView or link to it externally using [HostServices](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument(java.lang.String)).  You could study the help system used within Idea to see how they generally do that, e.g. help menus used, key commands responded to, icons used to link to the help system, etc.

Generally, the way it works is:

1. The document is written in markdown then processed and rendered to html.
2. The html documents have copious anchors throughout.
3. The help menu items link to the anchors directly.
4. Help menus and shortcut keys follow platform specific conventions and differ between Windows and Mac.
5. There is a single `?` icon in dialogs which appears in a consistent place and it links to an anchor in the html for context sensitive help in the dialog.
6. The documentation itself is hosted on a website so it can be accessed independently of the application.
7. The app launches an external browser to view the help rather than using something like a WebView to show the help internally.

Additionally, Idea will use tooltips which show up on hover.  Tooltips aren't used for every control or UI element, only certain ones.  If there is a keyboard accelerator which can be used to trigger the control action, then there is a tooltip for it, and in the tooltip it lets you know what the keyboard shortcut to trigger it is.

The rendered HTML to which the app is linked is hosted at the [jetbrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.2/discover-intellij-idea.html).

**Linking to HTML help**

You could:

1. Link to your own hosted website, OR
2. Link to html files packaged with your app.

Both could be rendered by either WebView or a browser showing a document using HostServices, using the `file:` protocol to access html files packaged with your app or `https:` protocol for files hosted on your web server.

**What does SceneBuilder do?**

For a pure JavaFX application, SceneBuilder is quite large and complex.  It has no reliance on internal help at all, just a single help menu item, accessible via an `F1` shortcut.  The help links to a [website authored and hosted by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) (using the standard tool Oracle use for authoring most Java platform docs, which is likely a commercial tool).  It is not as nicely integrated and context sensitive as the Idea example but it does demonstrate a simple approach to documenting an app via an external website.

Comment: Thanks for the Info, I'm trying to keep the help content contained within the app itself and not redirected out to a web browser, though that might be best way to handle it.  I currently use HTML in the app using Javas built in HTML objects for presenting the text, but as I said I don't really like the way it's turning out. It doesn't have the same look and feel of the app itself though I might be able to massage it to achieve that.

Comment: "Javas built in HTML objects for presenting the text" -> what is that?

Comment: I currently use WebView - though I was unaware of HostServices which you posted in your edit ... it looks promising.

Comment: In fact after looking at the steps you posted ... perhaps I could still keep things self contained using a combination of things ... you've definitely given me info I didn't have before I asked the question so I'm going to explore this method and see how it works out.